# JS setInterval() mem leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, setinterval

I know it's bunch of questions and answers here about this problem, but I don't know if it's realy applies to mine case.

I have a time script, with `setInterval` function. It works fine, for first minutes, but then in chrome/opera task manager I see that tab with this script running going from 40mb to 2-3gb! It's insane, and I don't know how to fix that. Only if rewrite all script in a different way.

Script:

```
function checkTime(i) {
    return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
};

function calcTime(city, offset) {
    d = new Date();
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset)),
        h = checkTime(nd.getHours()),
        m = checkTime(nd.getMinutes()),
        s = checkTime(nd.getSeconds());
    return nd.toLocaleString();
};

function updateTime() {
    if (document.getElementById('timeMoscow')) {
        calcTime('Moscow', '+3');
        document.getElementById('timeMoscow').innerHTML = h + ":" + m /*+ ":" + s*/;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('timeKiev')) {
        calcTime('Kiev', '+2');
        document.getElementById('timeKiev').innerHTML = h + ":" + m /*+ ":" + s*/;
    } else 
    if (document.getElementById('timeAstana')) {
        calcTime('Astana', '+6');
        document.getElementById('timeAstana').innerHTML = h + ":" + m /*+ ":" + s*/;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('timeNewYork')) {
        calcTime('NewYork', '-4');
        document.getElementById('timeNewYork').innerHTML = h + ":" + m /*+ ":" + s*/;
    }
    setInterval(updateTime, 500); //Problem
}

updateTime();
```

Comment: I see stackoverflow :)

Comment: `setInterval` repeats automatically, you don't have to re-call it. You're confusing it with `setTimeout`.

Comment: Well you are recursively setting up interval which in turn calls `updateTime` which again sets up Interval to call `updateTime` and this happens again and again until you run out of memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are recursively invoking `updateTime` function that using `setInterval` which is repeatedly calls `updateTime`. Remove `setInterval()` call from the method and invoke it like.

```
function updateTime() {
    //You rest of code
}

setInterval(updateTime, 500);
```